okhttp3 get result from proxy server,but not real result
guys, the question confused me for some days.
backgroud:
we use okhttp3(version 4.2.0) to get api response for java，for network cause,we must use proxy server( server not need config auth info),everything seems ok at first, when url is not exist,we expect okhttp3 return 404,504 ...anycode is ok,but we just get 200 from proxy server.any one give some tips would be thanks.
i am already tried update okhttp3 version to latest(version 5.0.0--alpa 14),nothing happen.i am using jdk17.
any tips will be grateful;

solved. by adding network check in application interceptor manual.but why frame not add the check backgroud.i can see the frame check proxy network issue auto,so i missed some settings or something else?
